# HQL order by many to many collection property

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have a hibernate object called `User` which has a many-to-many relationship with another hibernate object called `Post`. The relationship is called `likedPosts` (from the `User` perspective).

```
<set name="likedPosts" lazy="true" table="Likes" where="Deleted=0">
        <cache usage="read-write"/>
        <key column="UserID"/>
        <many-to-many column="PostID" class="Post"/>
    </set>
```

And currently I have a simple HQL query to return the list of liked posts as follows:

```
"select user.likedPosts from User user where user.id=:uid"
```

What I would like is to have this list ordered by a property in the `Post` object (specifically the post id). My (naive) attempt to do this was this:

```
"select user.likedPosts from User user where user.id=:uid 
        order by user.likedPosts.id desc"
```

This doesn't work though - I get an exception telling me I'm not allowed to do this. How would I go about doing this? Thanks!

Stack trace for error:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection [user0_.ID.likedPosts] with element property reference [id] [select user.likedPosts from com.pashash.domain.User user where user.id=:uid order by user.likedPosts.id desc]
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.DotNode$1.buildIllegalCollectionDereferenceException(DotNode.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.DotNode.checkLhsIsNotCollection(DotNode.java:513)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.DotNode.resolve(DotNode.java:221)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.resolve(HqlSqlWalker.java:728)
    ...
```

Comment: Print stacktrace of excpetion.

Comment: Why don't just get the user with session.Get<User> and then look at his likes (and order them in memory)? It would be much more OO style, persistence ignorant etc ... and may be even faster when the user and his likes are already in memory.

Comment: Good question. Two reasons: First, I would like to be able to limit the number of likes returned from the db (which `createQuery` allows me to do). Second, the result of this query is going to be cached by hibernate in the second level cache, so getting I'm guessing It'll be more efficient than me resorting it on every request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need an explicit join to do that:

```
select post from User user
inner join user.likedPosts post
where user.id = :userId
order by post.id desc
```

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to avoid using an explicit join, but this solves my problem perfectly! Typo in your answer: should be `where user.id = :userId`